# SYCL GPU device query - Is the GPU device is discrete or integtated?

Tags: gpu, sycl, discrete, integrated

I write a SYCL application for which I need to distinguish between GPU discrete devices and GPU integrated devices. Is there any way, directly or indirectly, to know if the GPU device I selected
(for example: by gpu_selector()) is discrete GPU or integrated GPU?
I did not find an aspect for this.

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in way of detecting an iGPU. However, on x86, I think the only officially supported iGPUs for compute are Intel's (U)HD graphics. ROCm doesn't appear to support AMD iGPUs right now. You could use a regex to detect the device name in your own device selector. There is more work if you want to ignore iGPUs on ARM platforms, I'm not aware of an ARM device with an iGPU that supports external GPUs anyway.

Comment: You'd think that an Intel CPU with an AMD GPU is discrete, but that combination actually exists as a sort-of integrated APU.

Comment: Re: "ROCm doesn't appear to support AMD iGPUs right now." While ROCm does not support iGPUs officially, it happily detects them and allows running code on them (at least on Linux), well enough to be used by the main developer of AdaptiveCpp (aka hipSYCL), see e.g. discussion in https://github.com/AdaptiveCpp/AdaptiveCpp/issues/1236.

Comment: The term iGPU is vague and arguably ill-defined, as there is only a fuzzy border between iGPU and discrete devices (e.g. NVIDIA Grace-Hopper has a tight integration between CPU and GPU, but is it an iGPU?). I would recommend to instead think about which guarantees you need: Do you need some kind of memory coherency between CPU and GPU? Do you need atomics to work across CPU/GPU? Do you need regular malloc() memory to be device-accessible? These questions can be answered much more clearly, and you will find that they are better covered by SYCL queries for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, there are no dedicated aspect or property.

With Intel oneAPI, you can query (deprecated, but still working) `info::device::host_unified_memory` device property. I verified with oneAPI 2024.0 that it works for integrated and discreet Intel GPUs; and, based on the [source code](https://github.com/oneapi-src/unified-runtime/blob/95db255a6e192af5bc00d465146325cb78210922/source/adapters/hip/device.cpp#L433-L441), it should work like this for NVIDIA and AMD GPUs too. But it is an implementation detail and is not guaranteed to behave like this in any future releases.

I don't see a way to do this with AdaptiveCpp / hipSYCL: the `host_unified_memory` property is always `false` for CUDA/HIP/OpenCL devices.

Another option with oneAPI is querying [`sycl::ext::intel::info::device::device_id`](https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/4ab007dfad339c28caa4a4d6ecc31e25c50fcc2a/sycl/doc/extensions/supported/sycl_ext_intel_device_info.md) property to get a PCI Device ID for Intel GPU. This can later be checked against [the official device list](https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/hardware-table.html). However, this will not work for NVIDIA or AMD GPUs. But, at this point, it might be easier to simply search the device name for keywords :)

Comment: aland, I'm not sure if you can see the answer I got from Intel. I posted a link here but it seems that it was deleted. The answer I got for Intel is as follows:

Comment: aland, I'm not sure if you can see the answer I got from Intel. I posted a link here but it seems that it was deleted. The answer I got for Intel is as follows: If you query the device name of an integrated device you will get something like that: "Device name: Intel(R) UHD Graphics  P630 [0x3e96]. For discrete device you will get: "Intel(R) Data Center GPU Max 1100". Now, the [0x3e96] is the PCI Device id. According to Intel, If the PCI Device id appears in device name -> it is integrated device otherwise it is not. Weird, this is Intel answer. See Intel forum: Intel® oneAPI Data Parallel C++

Comment: @Ami: Hm, I looked at values of `sycl::info::device::name` with recent compiler/drivers, and I get "Intel(R) Arc(TM) A770 Graphics" and "Intel(R) UHD Graphics 770", no PCI Device ID in either of them. Some older version of the runtime included PCI Device ID in the name, but then it was there for both integrated and discreet GPUs.

Comment: I added a slightly different solution based on PCI Device ID to my answer for the sake of completeness, but I would not advise using it: it requires you to maintain a list of all devices, and only works for Intel GPUs.

Comment: aland, I agree with you that this solution is not realistic.